# Combine or merge attribute options/labels in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute, layered-navigation, filter

I have 1 attribute (dropdown) that i use in layered navigation.
Is there a way i can merge/combine multiple dropdown options/labels to just 1 label/option in the layered navigation?
I have tried mydomain.com/category1/?attribute1=option1&attribute1=option2 but i get not the results i want (it only shows products with option2).

For a complete picture:
I use the filter for suppliers (my own products, dropship and 3th party products). People can filter by supplier but the problem is with the dropship suppliers. I want to combine those suppiers with my own shop/products filter so those products show-up under that filter and don't have their own filters.

I can solve the problem with hiding the dropship suppliers from the navigation with a 1x1 blank image but that won't hide the product count (i can disable the counter if that is needed but i like it when i can still use it.)
I know there is a extension that will do almost the same but i don't want a extension and that extension is not hiding the attribute options i want to hide.

Answer (score 1):

So you have different products with different attributes.  And all this attributes are shown as filters. You want to hide some attributes.

The solution is to open the unwanted attribute in admin > catalog > attributes > manage attributes   and set "Used in Layered Navigation" to "No"